Possible to use avr-debugger by jdolinay and rc-switch by sui77 together on arduino in vsc?
I'm building a buzzersystem with 433mhz remote controls. the basic setup is working, but now I need a debugger. I'm using visual studio code and platformio. Everyone is recommending the avr-debugger package. But I think the rc-switch package has some external interrupts (as far is I could read the erros and forums) which is preventing to use those to packages together. Normally I'm just a Unity guy so this is all new. I rebuilt/copied small parts in a new project, where the debugger was save working to see that beside the Serial.print (which I allready read) the defining of my rcswitch is already making problems. Is there another debugger to use or can I make them work together somehow? The git is https://github.com/LosKartoflos/ArduinoBuzzer.git
Headerfile
#ifndef RECIEVEDATA_H
#define RECIEVEDATA_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include "avr8-stub.h"

int loopRecieveData();
void setupRecieveData();

#endif

The line causing the first error:
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch;


